# Serilog.Expressions SubLogger on Log Levels to Multiple Files

Tags: logging, serilog

I am getting the files to create in the logs folder, however they are empty. All except backup, which has all logs. Also if I keep in the

```
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
```

inside the sublogger file args it will not create the file, which then does not give me a datestamp on the files. Why?

If I am missing something to help with this puzzle, I would gladly add it.

My logger calls:

```
 Logger.LogCritical("Crtical");
 Logger.LogDebug("Debug");
 Logger.LogInformation("Information");
 Logger.LogError("Error");
 Logger.LogTrace("Trace");
 Logger.LogWarning("Warning");
```

NuGet References:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="6.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" Version="8.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="1.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
```

Here is my serilog appsettings:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Async", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:g} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:g} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}",
          "path": "logs\\Backup.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": "7",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@Level = 'Error'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:g} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}",
                  "path": "logs\\error.log",
                  "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@Level = 'Information' or @Level = 'Debug' or @Level = 'Warning' or @Level = 'Fatal'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:g} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}",
                  "path": "logs\\standard.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": "7",
                  "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter",
                  "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Application"
    }
  }
```

my output in backup.log:

```
[04/26/2021 14:20 FTL] [xxSoureContextxx] Crtical
[04/26/2021 14:20 INF] [xxSoureContextxx] Information
[04/26/2021 14:20 ERR] [xxSoureContextxx] Error
[04/26/2021 14:20 WRN] [xxSoureContextxx] Warning
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is the issue, but using _Serilog.Expressions_, the level property is called `@l`, not `@Level`. HTH!

Answer (score 4):

Serilog.Filter.Expressions is deprecated but its syntax is @Level. As Nicholas pointed out in a comment above, Serilog.Expressions uses a syntax of @l. Everything worked including getting a file while using the interval.

Thanks Nicholas.